# launch roscore from launch file

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a launch file that plays back a bag file and launches some data processing nodes. The problem is that `rosbag play` fails if no master is running. Can I start this process from a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202783/launch-roscore-from-launch-file/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch will automatically start a roscore if there isn't already one running.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3